# Laravel - Redirect in Model Binding executes controller method

Tags: php, laravel, exception, routes, model-binding

I've got a system which lists sports players, and am using model binding in Laravel 5.2 to fetch the player model based on a slug in the URL. In some cases, the spelling of a players name might have changed, so I have an intermediate table where I look for the old slug, and if it is found replace it with the new slug in the URL and redirect to the new URL. Locally this works fine, and on my live server it also works, but on live it logs an exception which seems to indicate that the route's controller method gets run even on redirect.

Route:

```
Route::get('{playerSlug}', ['as' => 'player.main', 'uses' => 'PlayersController@player']);
```

Binding:

```
Route::bind('playerSlug', function($value)
{
    $player = Player::getPlayerBySlug($value);

    if ( ! $player)
    {
        return App::abort(404);
    }
    elseif(is_string($player))
    {
        return \Redirect::to(URL::to($player), 301)->send();
    }
    else
    {
        return $player;
    }
});
```

Start of controller method:

```
public function player($wordPlayers, $player, $scope = null)
    {
        $season = $player->latestSeason();
```

Exception:

```
[2016-02-19 00:34:56] production.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Method [latestSeason] does not exist on Redirect. in /home/forge/cuetracker.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php:198
Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/app/Http/Controllers/PlayersController.php(72): Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse->__call('latestSeason', Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\PlayersController->player('Players', Object(Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse))
#2 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9137): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9199): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('player', Array)
#4 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9179): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\PlayersController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'player')
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9656): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9180): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#10 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9167): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\PlayersController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'player')
#11 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8262): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'player')
#12 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8249): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(7977): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9656): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(7978): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(7969): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(7959): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2381): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13111): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9666): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11675): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9666): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12850): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9666): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#37 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12787): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9666): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#42 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(3183): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9666): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#47 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/app/Http/Middleware/EnableQueryLog.php(18): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\EnableQueryLog->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9666): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#52 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9656): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2328): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#57 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2312): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 /home/forge/cuetracker.net/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 {main}
```

Hope someone can help me, please let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected behavior, I suppose.

Model binding lets you customize how to return the data from the model for **that route parameter** (in your case `{playerSlug}`), but you anyway end into a controller method or a closure.